# Should I git-push a dist folder of a npm package

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, tsdx

The JS package I've prepared (using tsdx) is being used across multiple company systems. It lies within our gitlab so the package.json entry looks like this:

```
"some-package": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.company.com:some-place/some-package.git#some-branch"
```

Now, every time a user does `npm install` it takes a large amount of time until the process completes. Is it because of me pushing a src/ folder instead of dist/ (which I do)? Does the package builds itself every time it gets downloaded by `npm install`? Should I push dist/ folder to shorten the time needed to complete `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

Npm install are downloading all your dependencies and placing them I the node_modules folder.

The dist folder is typically for your builded application, so committing and pushing the dist folder wouldn't help on the process time..

Answer (score 0):

No, pushing dist folder is unnecessary as it automatically creates dist folder when `npm run start` is runned.